# iPhone 5s screen goes black during a phone call

Tags: iphone

When I end a phone call I find that the screen has gone black. I have to turn it on and re-enter my password to hang up. Is there a way to keep the phone from turning black during a call? The call is not affected.

Comment: I have the same problem. When I am using the speaker or ear buds the screen goes black. Very annoying. I need to go on and off mute frequently and I have to re-enter my password every time because the screen goes black.

Answer (score 2):

Is your phone in a protective case?  My wife's iPhone does the same thing because her case is loose and slides over the proximity sensor and thinks it's still by her face.

The screen turns black because of a proximity sensor on the phone. This is to save battery during a call, and to protect the buttons from being pressed when it's up against your face. This feature can not be disabled. The only way I have been able to prevent the screen from turning black during a call is by using a Bluetooth headset, earbuds, or speakerphone during the call, and never bringing it close enough to the face to trigger the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a hard reset or restored to factory settings? That your screen goes black when you hold it against your ear is normal. But it should turn on again when you remove it from your ear.